# API call returning undefined AND input value returning returning no value

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, web-applications

I'm currently working on two web apps, one a weather app, and the other a simple login page. I will post explanations for each, as well as the code snippets below the explanations. Thanks to anyone who is willing or able to help.

Edit: The weather app has been updated based on the feedback and now works!

For the weather application, I am using an API to gather weather data, and part of that data is the location. In my JS file, I am trying to obtain the city location from the input field and concatenate it to the API. I've read numerous answers on this site and elsewhere to figure out what I am doing wrong, but nothing seems to work. When comparing my code to others it appears that everything should be working and the inputValue should pass the city location; instead, the inputValue always returns empty. Any reason why this would be happening?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //var button = document.querySelector('#submitButton');
  var inputValue = document.querySelector('#inputValue').value;
  var apiID = config.API_ID;
  var apiURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + inputValue + "&units=imperial&appid=" + apiID;



$('#submitButton').click(function(){
      $.getJSON(apiURL, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      document.getElementById('weather').innerHTML = data['weather'][0]['description'];
      //document.getElementById('geo').innerHTML = "latitude: " + data.current_observation.display_location.latitude + " longitude: " + data.current_observation.display_location.longitude;
      document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = data.main.temp;
      document.getElementById('city').innerHTML = data.name;
      document.getElementById('country').innerHTML = data.sys.country;
      document.getElementById('icon').src= data.weather.icon;
  });
});

    

});
```

For the login app, what I am trying to do here is connect it to a calendar API so that the background color/image changes depending on the holiday (currently have it set for a day of the week to test). I keep getting two primary problems. First: I have consistently received a CORS response, but after speaking with the developer of the API, they have informed me that they do not use CORS and the issue I'm facing is likely to do with my choice in browser. That is something I can [hopefully] figure out on my own. Second: the API is consistently returning an undefined Key, despite having the Key stashed in a Config file. I have used Config files on other projects and they tend to work, so I'm uncertain as to why it is failing to properly return the key here. I have checked for syntax and indentation issues, but that doesn't appear to be the problem. I have even tested by placing the API key directly inside of the JS file, but when I run the application it still returns empty (despite working when I place the API+Key directly in the browser). Does anyone know why this would be happening, and how to fix it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var api_Key = config.API_KEY;
    var apiURL = "https://holidayapi.com/v1/holidays?pretty&country=US&year=2020&key=" + api_Key;
    
    
    $("#register-form").hide();
    
     $.getJSON(apiURL, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      if(data.holidays.weekday.date.name = "Saturday"){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = rgb(20, 65, 37);
    }
    

      
     
  });
});
```

Comment: weather: you set your url when the page loads.  You need to put the `inputValue=` *and* the `var apiURL` *inside* the click event so the url matches the input value at the time the getJSON runs, not when the page loads.

Comment: *likely to do with my choice in browser* sounds like a b*llsh** answer, like "rats eat the cables so you can't have a network card"

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you! That fixed the weather app. I don't know why I didn't think of that, but at least now I know.